# Magento 1.9 - The export error after customizing grid on shipment page

Tags: magento-1.9, database, grid, export

I got a issue about export our shipment information.
Before i start with this issue, i add the "shipping method"column, is called customizing column, on shipment grid!

Like this,

> app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Shipment/Grid.php

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
    /*$collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method'));*/
     $collection->getSelect()->join('sales_flat_order', 'main_table.entity_id = sales_flat_order.entity_id',array('shipping_method'));


    $this->setCollection($collection);
    return parent::_prepareCollection();
}


protected function _prepareColumns()
{
parent::_prepareColumns();

$this->removeColumn('created_at');

$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
$shippingmethods = array();
foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
    if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
        if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
            $_title = $_ccode;
        foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
            $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
            $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
        }
    }
}

$this->addColumn('created_at', array(
    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
    'index'     => 'created_at',
    'type'      => 'datetime',
    'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
));

$this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
    'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
    'width' => '80px',
    'type'  => 'options',
    'index' => 'shipping_method',
    'options' => $shippingmethods,
));
```

$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->**('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->**('Excel XML'));

return $this;
}
**I can see the column** i created but after export
On the sales -> shipment on back-end page, i faced this issue!

[image]
And log said

```
ERR (3): Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): &lt;/html&gt; in /home/kbethos/public_html/wh-clone/app/code/core/Mage/AdminN‌​otification/Model/Fe‌​ed.php on line 173
```

I guess it is resulted from that i deal with nothing with database. So The back-end page didn't bring the shipping method value from the table.

Do i need to join the tables directly?

The table which has the shipment grid informaion is "sales_flat_shipment_grid"
And there is shipping description(shipping method) on "sales_flat_order"

**Then, How can i export these grid info ? Thank you**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means that MySQL is not able to filter the results because column `created_at` is in both used tables and it doesn't know which one to use. You have to set something like that on `created_at` column for this grid :

```
protected function _prepareColumns()
{
parent::_prepareColumns();

$this->removeColumn('created_at');

$methods = Mage::getSingleton('shipping/config')->getActiveCarriers();
    $shippingmethods = array();
    foreach($methods as $_ccode => $_carrier) {
        if($_methods = $_carrier->getAllowedMethods())  {
            if(!$_title = Mage::getStoreConfig("carriers/$_ccode/title"))
                $_title = $_ccode;
            foreach($_methods as $_mcode => $_method)   {
                $_code = $_ccode . '_' . $_mcode;
                $shippingmethods[$_code]= $_title;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
        'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Date Shipped'),
        'index'     => 'created_at',
        'type'      => 'datetime',
        'filter_index' => 'main_table.created_at'
    ));

    $this->addColumn('shipping_method', array(
        'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Shipping Method'),
        'width' => '80px',
        'type'  => 'options',
        'index' => 'shipping_method',
        'options' => $shippingmethods,
    ));

$this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
$this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

return $this;
}
```

This should help.

Comment: Where do i have to this code? Could you let me know where i have to add it after specific line?

Comment: I add it to $this->addColumn('shipping_method', ~~ but it doesn't work

Comment: btw, When i click export, the website is stopped and finally, export is not proceeded. What should i do?

Comment: it works! Thank you!